# Who does Sasha Blake steal the wallet from in Jennifer Egan's "A Visit from the Goon Squad"?

Tags: jennifer-egan, a-visit-from-the-goon-squad

I having been filling out the character map in Jennifer Egan's *A Visit from the Goon Squad*.  In significant events each character maps to another specific character.

What is the name of the character who Sasha Blake steals and then returns the wallet from in the first chapter?

Comment: Are you certain that this character has a name?

Comment: @PeterShor no i'm not. but characters keep popping up in  little sidebars with names. i'm wondering if i missed it.